# Is possible to run a Watchdog in OneDrive Clound?

Tags: python, rest, cloud, onedrive, python-watchdog

I was trying to figure out if it is possible to run a python script (watchdog) to monitor when a file is inserted into a folder that is hosted by the OneDrive platform. I work in a company and we want to monitor a folder that is shared with everyone. And I think that a program that is able to monitor OneDrive Side is better than installing the same program for all clients of this OneDrive Clound application. Because I can't guarantee that local changes will be loaded and shared with everyone, and some users could make the mistake of stopping the monitoring program.

Comment: What about this:
https://github.com/teamdatatonic/gcp-watchdog

its google, but maybe it helps